# A regex pattern which is hard for me

Tags: regex

i'm beginner on regex.
I need to do this :

```
wanna match : (bkz: bakınız) 
wanna match : (bkz:falan filan) 
wanna match : (bkz: falan filan) 
wanna match : (bkz: sen kimsin?) 
wanna match : (bkz: ali ata bak)
wanna match : (bkz : selam)
wanna match : (bkz: ŞEYTAN)
wanna match : (bkz:ateş!)
wanna match : (bkz: ali)
wanna match : (bkz: ALİCAN) 
wanna match : (bkz: ali ata bak)
wanna match : (bkz:a) 
wanna match : (bkz ali)
wanna match : (bkz. deneme)
DONT WANNA PARSE : (bkz : http://google.com.tr)
DONT WANNA PARSE : (bkz: ) 
DONT WANNA PARSE :(bkz. (bkz: sss))
DONT WANNA PARSE :(bkz (bkz. (bkz: sss)))
```

my regex so far: `/(?<!(?:bkz: ))(?:\(bkz.?[:;\. ]?)([\w şŞüÜçÇıİğĞöÖ?!]+)\)/gmi`

See it live: http://regex101.com/r/pK6yZ1/4

What do I need to do?

Comment: Multiline text from user input, I want to parse;

(bkz: **THIS**)
(bkz **THIS**)
(bkz; **THIS**)
(bkz. **THIS**)

and not;

(bkz (bkz: **NOT THIS**) 
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?!.*?bkz:\s*\))(?:(?!bkz[:;. ]).)*?(?:\(bkz.?[:;\. ]?)([\w şŞüÜçÇıİğĞöÖ?!]+)\)
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?!.*?bkz:\s*\))` Asserts that there wouldn't be `bkz:` followed by zero or more more spaces and a `)` symbol.
- `(?:(?!bkz[:;. ]).)*?` Matches any char  but not of `bkz[; :.]` zero or more times. This ensures that there wouldn't be any `bkz` present before.
- `(?:\(bkz.?[:;\. ]?)` matches `bkz` and a following optional char plus the following optional character from the griven list.
- `([\w şŞüÜçÇıİğĞöÖ?!]+)` Captures one or more chars from the given list.

Comment: @BatuhanKATIRCI [Accept an answer which helped you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
/(?<!(?:\(bkz[ \.][ \.]))\(bkz ?[:;\. ] ?((?:[\wşŞüÜçÇıİğĞöÖ?!] ?)+)\)/gmi
```

It could be seen as

- `(?<!(?:\(bkz[ \.][ \.]))` --> Dont match words starting with bkz
- `\(bkz ?[:;\. ] ?` --> Look for words having bkz and a separator
- `((?:[\wşŞüÜçÇıİğĞöÖ?!] ?)+))`  --> followed by 1 or more words

Comment: Your version is shorter, but not catching inputs

Comment: I validated the regex with your input. whats wrong?

Comment: Your pattern can't catch user inputs.
(bkz: fetch me) -> i need to catch "parse me" -> $1

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I misread your question. I edited the answer if you still want to work with a shorter expression. The right expression is this: (?<!(?:\(bkz[ \.][ \.]))\(bkz ?[:;\. ] ?((?:[\wşŞüÜçÇıİğĞöÖ?!] ?)+)\)